# usage of subscript within For loop in R

Tags: r

I am having very basic doubt in R. 
I am having a table like this:

```
A   B   C   D   E
7   1   6   8   7
9   3   9   5   9
4   6   2   1   10
10  5   3   4   1
1   3   5   9   3
6   4   8   7   6
```

I am in the process of finding correlation of each variable with every other variable in the table. The final report should be something like this:

```
Var_1   Var_2   Correlation
    A   A         1
    A   B       -0.022991544
    A   C        0.231553
    A   D       -0.28037
    A   E       -0.00523
    B   A       -0.022999
    B   B         1
    …       
    …       
    E   D       -0.39223    
    E   E         1
```

The below is the R code i am using to achieve this:

```
rm(list=ls())
test <- read.csv("D:/AB/test.csv")
iterations <- ncol(test)
correlation <- matrix(ncol = 3 , nrow = iterations)
for (k in 1:iterations) {
  for (l in 1:iterations){
    corr <- cor(test[,k], test[,l])

    corr_string_A <- names(test[k])
    corr_string_B <- names(test[l])
    correlation[l,] <- rbind(corr_string_A, corr_string_B, corr)        
  }
}
```

But i am ending up getting only the output of E variables:

```
> correlation
     [,1] [,2] [,3]                 
[1,] "E"  "A"  "-0.0523026032815805"
[2,] "E"  "B"  "0"                  
[3,] "E"  "C"  "0.231900361745681"  
[4,] "E"  "D"  "-0.392232270276368" 
[5,] "E"  "E"  "1"
```

I understand that somewhere in the twin For loops that is used in the above code has a looping issue and hence only the "E" series is printed. I am not able to figure it out.

If anyone can kindly help me, it would be really great.

**EDIT***

Changing the input data a bit

```
    A   B   C   D   E
    0   0   6   8   7
    0   0   9   5   9
    0   0   2   1   10
    0   0   3   4   1
    0   0   5   9   3
    0   0   8   7   6
```

If one of the columns are having 0, the correlation value that we will get would be 'NaN'. I want to handle 'NaN', replace with some other value according the business specification. Sorry for the late addition. Thank you for your understanding.

Comment: Doesn't just `cor(test)` gives you what you need already?

Comment: This would be much easier with `reshape2::melt(cor(df))`

Comment: @DavidArenburg - Thank you very much for the suggestion. That is working However i wanted to have a report like displayed above. Thanks again.

Comment: @MrFlick - Thank you very much. This was a very quick solution and it helped. However, in my work, i am using few more if conditions in between the code that i have shown. Hence if some adjustment to the above code will be helpful. Thanks again for the brilliant answer.

Comment: @MrFlick - I would like to elaborate a little bit more. Say for example, at my work, i might get a column with completely filled with zeros. In that case the correlation between two columns will be Null or NA.  To satisify my requirement, i should not have NA. I will replace NA with certain other number based on the business condition. This was the reason why i wanted to write this code. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question without altering your code too much, there are two main issues. First, you are not allocating a matrix of the correct size. There are five interations of five variables, or 25 combinations (with doubling of some combinations, ie A/C = C/A) in this example, so you need to fix your matrix declaration to account for that:

```
correlation <- matrix(ncol = 3 , nrow = iterations * iterations)
```

Second, you are only assigning values to the first five columns of this matrix within your nested for loop. This line:

```
correlation[l,] <- rbind(corr_string_A, corr_string_B, corr)
```

Needs to have a value greater than `l` (which can only reach 5 in the example) after the first time through the nested loop, like this:

```
correlation[l + ((k-1) * iterations),] <- rbind(corr_string_A, corr_string_B, corr)
```

This code should fix those problems:

```
iterations <- ncol(test)
correlation <- matrix(ncol = 3 , nrow = iterations * iterations)
for (k in 1:iterations) {
  for (l in 1:iterations){
    corr <- cor(test[,k], test[,l])
    corr_string_A <- names(test[k])
    corr_string_B <- names(test[l])
    correlation[l + ((k-1) * iterations),] <- rbind(corr_string_A, corr_string_B, corr)        
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The Hmisc package has an rcorr function that will return a list whose first item is the correlation matrix. It requires a matrix as input, which the function data.matrix is designed to deliver. The transformation to a three column format is accomplished by the as.data.frame.table function:

```
library(Hmisc)
as.data.frame.table( rcorr(data.matrix(dat))[[1]] )
#-------
   Var1 Var2        Freq
1     A    A  1.00000000
2     B    A -0.02299154
3     C    A  0.23155349
4     D    A -0.28036851
5     E    A -0.05230260
6     A    B -0.02299154
7     B    B  1.00000000
8     C    B -0.58384037
9     D    B -0.80175394
10    E    B  0.00000000
11    A    C  0.23155349
12    B    C -0.58384037
13    C    C  1.00000000
14    D    C  0.52094591
15    E    C  0.23190036
16    A    D -0.28036851
17    B    D -0.80175394
18    C    D  0.52094591
19    D    D  1.00000000
20    E    D -0.39223227
21    A    E -0.05230260
22    B    E  0.00000000
23    C    E  0.23190036
24    D    E -0.39223227
25    E    E  1.00000000
```

The `names<-` function can be used to dress up column names to your specification.

Comment: Thanks for the response. This worked. I have a question. Suppose that one of the columns is completely zero. In that case I am ending up with "NaN". I want to replace these "NaN" with certain value based on the business condition at my work. Is that possible with this code? Please advise.

Comment: With a dataframe named 'dat', one can simply use `dat[is.na(dat)] <- val`, where 'val' has the desired (numeric) value..

Comment: Thank you again. This might help. But our business conditions are still more complex. When if it is 'NaN' I might check for the more than one condition before replacing the values by val. That was the reason why i had to write the above code. Thanks again for the useful piece of information.

Comment: to make it more clarity on the business requirement, i have edited the question and provided one more input file. Here col A & B are having zeroes and C,D&E are having some numbers. This is how the answer should look. A & A --> Corr 1 (which is already appearing correctly). A & B -- both are having zeroes, The output should display '1' because both are having same values. A & C --> One col with zero and another col with 1, hence the correlation value should be '0'. For the columns with real numbers, correlation should be the actual value received from 'cor' function,.

Comment: I would be able to achieve this if i could correct the R code.

Comment: I just tested my suggestion for reassignment to the locations of NaN on the results of your new example and it "worked" as expected.